Refresh Developer Pro sandbox from another Developer Pro sandbox
We have seen that when we refresh a Developer Pro sandbox from another Developer Pro sandbox, it comes with all its data including standard objects, custom objects and custom settings.
While this is very useful since it avoids manual data loading, the documentation suggests that only custom settings and certain standard objects like Product2 and Pricebook2 should be copied over.
Is the documentation incorrect?  Does this not make them better than Partial Copy sandboxes since everything gets copied by default?
